# Setting line cap style doesn't work UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

This is my code:

```
    let cross = UIBezierPath()
    cross.move(to: CGPoint(x: skull.bounds.maxX, y: skull.bounds.minY))
    cross.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: skull.bounds.minX, y: skull.bounds.maxY))
    cross.close()
    UIColor.red.set()
    cross.lineWidth = 3.0
    cross.lineCapStyle = .round
    cross.stroke()
```

I want to round the end of the line, but it's still square, how should I do it?

Comment: I think your line is getting cut since you are using the max frame to draw the line, reduce the max, min values by 5, see what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just tested on PlayGround, Hope it will help

```
let cross = UIBezierPath()
cross.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 100)) // your point
cross.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)) // your point
cross.closePath()
cross.lineWidth = 23.0
cross.lineJoinStyle = .Round
cross.stroke()
```

**Swift 5.0**

```
let cross = UIBezierPath()
cross.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 100)) // your point
cross.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)) // your point
cross.close()
cross.lineWidth = 23.0
cross.lineJoinStyle = .round
cross.stroke()
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The *line cap* style configures the style of the line ending. You have closed path, i.e. you have no line ending.

You are probably looking for the *line join* style, which affects all "corners" or "vertexes" of a path.

Alternatively, if you just want a straight, don't close the path. Otherwise you get two line segments: one from the starting point to the end point and another one back to the start.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.1 update to Umair Afzal's code:

```
let cross = UIBezierPath()
cross.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 100)) // your point
cross.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)) // your point
cross.lineWidth = 12
cross.lineCapStyle = .round
cross.stroke()
```